# java runs jmx disabled action

Tags: java, jmeter, jmx

Im using java to run jmx file which has disabled sampler. So I thought it would not run disabled sampler, but it does. This is jmx file code: as U can see `enabled="false"`

```
<HTTPSamplerProxy guiclass="HttpTestSampleGui" testclass="HTTPSamplerProxy" testname="Edit User All Parameters" enabled="false">
```

and Im using `org.apache.jmeter.save.SaveService;` class to load the file content:

```
 File jmxFile = new File(jmxFilePath);
      HashTree testPlanTree = null;
      try{
       testPlanTree = SaveService. loadTree(jmxFile);
      }catch(IOException ex){}
```

any idea how can i fix this issue ?

Answer (score 2):

My expectation is that your code is missing [JMeter.convertSubTree()](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/JMeter.html#convertSubTree(org.apache.jorphan.collections.HashTree)) method, as per JavaDoc

> **convertSubTree**
>
> ***public static void convertSubTree(HashTree tree)***
>
> Remove disabled elements Replace the ReplaceableController with the target subtree

So make sure you call it before you run your test

Example code (just in case you still need it), pay attention to `JMeter.convertSubTree(testPlanTree);` line

```
   //JMeter Home
   String jmeterHome = "c:/apps/jmeter";

   // JMeter Engine
   StandardJMeterEngine jmeter = new StandardJMeterEngine();

   // Initialize Properties, logging, locale, etc.
   JMeterUtils.loadJMeterProperties(jmeterHome + "bin/jmeter.properties");
   JMeterUtils.setJMeterHome(jmeterHome);
   JMeterUtils.initLogging();// you can comment this line out to see extra log messages of i.e. DEBUG level
   JMeterUtils.initLocale();

   // Initialize JMeter SaveService
   SaveService.loadProperties();

   // Load existing .jmx Test Plan
   HashTree testPlanTree = SaveService.loadTree(new File(jmeterHome + "bin/test.jmx"));

   // Remove disabled test elements
   JMeter.convertSubTree(testPlanTree);


   // Add summariser
   Summariser summer = null;
   String summariserName = JMeterUtils.getPropDefault("summariser.name", "summary");
   if (summariserName.length() > 0) {
       summer = new Summariser(summariserName);
   }


   // Store execution results into a .jtl file
   String logFile = jmeterHome + "/bin/test.jtl";
   ResultCollector logger = new ResultCollector(summer);
   logger.setFilename(logFile);
   testPlanTree.add(testPlanTree.getArray()[0], logger);

   // Run JMeter Test
   jmeter.configure(testPlanTree);
   jmeter.run();
```

See [Five Ways To Launch a JMeter Test without Using the JMeter GUI](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/5-ways-launch-jmeter-test-without-using-jmeter-gui) article to learn more about different ways of executing JMeter test.